# VB6 - How to list PIDs related to Usernames

Tags: list, process, vb6

I am still very new to VB6 and VB Studio.

I want to get a list of all the Process ID's and the Usernames associated with those ID's

I am not using a form, as no GUI will be needed, but for testing purposes, I would like to output the list to a msgbox or notepad file.

This is what I have got so far, but it does not run in VB Studio. It does work as a VBS, but will not save as an exe with the error "Invalid Outside Procedure"

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strList

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
strList = strList & vbCr & _
objProcess.Name
Next

WSCript.Echo strList
WScript.Quit
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Module to your project and use the code below. It writes the data out to a text file in the temp folder.  From the Project>Properties menu make sure the "Startup Object" is `Sub Main`.

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim objWMIService As Object
    Dim objProcess As Object
    Dim colProcess As Object
    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim strUserName
    Dim strUserDomain

    Sub Main()

        On Error GoTo eh

        strComputer = "."

        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
        & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

        Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

        Open "c:\temp\test.txt" For Output As #1
        For Each objProcess In colProcess
            objProcess.GetOwner strUserName, strUserDomain
            Print #1, objProcess.Name & vbTab & strUserName
        Next
        Close #1

        MsgBox ("Done")

        Exit Sub

    eh:
        MsgBox (Error$)

    End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for your time in helping me, I really appreciate it :)